# Wifi toggle key is not working on Dell Inspiron 15 3542 Touch

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, dell-inspiron

**WIFI TOGGLE KEY PROBLEM:**

I am facing this problem, where the <kbd>wifi toggle key</kbd> (with an antenna) which sits beside F12 key and shares the Print Screen functionality is not working on my Dell Inspiron 3542 laptop.

The combination as suggested on many websites is <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>wifi toggle key</kbd>. But in my case it isn't working.

When used in conjunction with **<kbd>Win</kbd>** key it works fine and takes a screenshot.

**"<kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd>" PROBLEM:**

Also, I am unable to change Funtion key behaviour using **<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>** combination.

The two very common alternatives are:

1. Changing the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key settings from the **BIOS**.(Unnecessary & a long one)
2. Changing it from the **Mobility center**.(Easy one)

These alternatives worked well but the "<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>"(easiest one) problem persists.

Please help me out with this dilemma.

**Edit:** These functionalities used to work an year ago. Moreover, I asked my friend who has the same model and has both the functionalities working.

Comment: This key combination is based on the required drivers for the device in question and the keyboard both being installed.

Comment: These combinations used to work an year ago or so. I don't understand what is the problem now.

Comment: Did you refresh or reset your system? You may need to reinstall the drivers by the manufacturer to get this working.

Comment: Yes I installed the latest version of QuickSet from Dell's Official Website. No use. It didn't work.